# Bluetooth error on my Nexus S

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-nexus-s

I have a Nexus S phone, GingerBread 2.3.5. When I start my phone, or try starting Bluetooth, it gives me an error saying:
'Application Bluetooth Share(process com.android.bluetooth) has stopped unexpectedly.'
Iam given only two options, Force close, and Report.
The exception is a Null pointer exception, and the source file is Parcel.java.
How do I solve this problem??
Also, I get a message saying I can update my phone to ICS 4.0.4. If I update, will that get rid of the Bluetooth problem??